# Is there any way to increase number characters in RAISEERROR message in MS SQL procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, raiseerror

I have a procedure in MS SQL, where front end receives a message whenever there is some error. RASIEERROR is truncating the message because the length is greater than 2048 chars. I also looked into Throw but it is also doing the same thing.

Links to refer:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Text from documentation

> msg_str  - Is a user-defined message with formatting similar to the printf function in the C standard library. The error message can have a maximum of 2,047 characters. If the message contains 2,048 or more characters, only the first 2,044 are displayed and an ellipsis is added to indicate that the message has been truncated.

Is there any way to increase the number of characters?

Comment: An error message of more than 2K characters is suspect to begin with. You could return the data (as I assume it's data that's being crammed in there) in a `SELECT` before the `RAISERROR`, and/or use output parameters. Both of these should be processed before the error kicks in. Inserting the data in a table and including a reference only in the message is another option, but this is trickier as often you can't perform new data operations when the error dooms the transaction you're in.

Comment: Why use `RAISERROR` when `THROW` is recommended? Though I agree, if you have an error that's 2,048+ characters long, there appears to be a bigger problem.

Comment: I am open to use THROW as well, if we can figure out how we can increase the number of allowed characters. @Larnu

Comment: That is a good suggestion, let me try to do that. Thanks @JeroenMostert

Comment: `THROW` has the same "limitation", though I don't see it as a real limitation as 2,048 characters is more than enough characters for an error; I would even suggest that 2,048 is too many as well. This, in truth, has the smell of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Note that the documentation doesn't say that this is a default, it says *this is the maximum*. Why then would you expect there'd be some way to lengthen it?

Comment: Ok! Thank you for your help. Let me rethink if there is a better way to do this. I never knew about XY Problem. But when i read about it - i found it really interesting and got your point

Comment: Raiserror can also be used for informational messages (error level 10, for example). There's nothing inherently suspicious about a long informational message.

Comment: For example, within a DACPAC, we have a legacy CDC operation failing. A particular column is getting left out of the column list for unknown reasons. I am trying to log the column list so that I can catch the error in the environments where the issue is occurring (there's nothing significant about this column, it's not even new). This table has a silly number of columns. I was trying to avoid having this operation be so significant to the log length (versus one `RAISERROR()` per column). Not all "error messages" are "ideal" because wacky things happen in some environments sometimes.